# Python telebot callback_query_handler

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: получаю инлайн сообщение, в ответ снова подставляю инлайн кнопку, срабатывает этот хэндлер `(lambda: true)` и сообщение с `callback_data='Y'` идет в первый IF `call.data.isdigit`, а должно в `elif call.data == 'Y'`

```
    text=str(parse.get_champ(call.data)[0]))
    IndexError: string index out of range

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def inline_handler(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data.isdigit(): #Если числовой ID
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                                  message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                  text=str(parse.get_champ(call.data)[0]))
            for i in parse.get_result(call.data):
                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                item = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Подписаться', callback_data='Y')
                keyboard.add(item)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text = str(i), reply_markup=keyboard)
        elif call.data == 'Y': # Если Y
            print('тут')
```

Comment: Уверены, что нажимается именно кнопка с *callback_data='Y'*?

Comment: @Anatol да, уверен. я разобрался вчера, вместо if call.data.isdigit(), вызывал if call.data.isdigit, поэтому все отрабатывало некорректно